# adding an amount of pixels saved in a variable to a css property in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add an amount of pixels, that is stored in my variable "x" to a css property in jQuery.

I know that since jQuery 1.6 you can easily use something like this:

```
$(this).css({top: "+=150"});
```

But when I use a variable instead of the 150 it doesn't work, since variables have to be written out of quotation marks.

```
$(this).css({top: "+= x"});
```

Comment: This will work: `$(this).css({top: "+=" + x });`. If you are using ES6, use [string interpolation for template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): `$(this).css({top: \`+={x}\` });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
$(this).css({top: "+= "+ x +"px"});
```

instead of your code